# Why do I get an error "no module named lal", when there is clearly a directory named 'lal'?

Tags: python-3.x

When I enter certain commands at the command prompt or in the python interpreter, I get an error message, no module named lal. But there is clearly a directory called lal in the same path from which I am running the command.

**Code and error message**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When posting a question, do not put any text as a screen print.  Images of text is quite useless, you can just copy-paste it directly in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do that, but SO refused to post my question with the text, saying that it looks like code and needs to be formatted/indented in a certain way, but it wasn't code. It was just the shell commands and the outputs and error messages. What do you suggest I could do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

In order for python to recognize `lal` as a module you either need to either:

- have a python script named `lal.py`.
- or a directory named `lal` **that contains a script called `__init__.py`**.

From what I see in from your terminal screenshot you don't have the required `__init__.py` file.

This file should be used to import any other functions/classes/etc. you want to be accessible via the `lal` module.

Comment: there is an __init__.py two levels above the lal directory. but there is no __init__.py within lal directory although there are other files and directories. Is the __init__.py file needed within lal?

Comment: "Each package in Python is a directory which MUST contain a special file called `__init__.py`. This file can be empty, and it indicates that the directory it contains is a Python package, so it can be imported the same way a module can be imported." [source](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages).